# How can you get Google Sketchup running?

Tags: 10.10

How can you get google sketchup to work on ubuntu?

Comment: if you don't give us a detailed error message we can provide good solutions (you may check http://wiki.winehq.org/GoogleSketchup)

Answer (score 4):

Google [Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=36208) is not available natively for Ubuntu, you will have to run it using Wine.
The following links may help you to get things going;

http://wiki.winehq.org/GoogleSketchup

http://ubuntuguide.net/install-google-sketchup-cad-style-app-in-ubuntu-using-wine

Answer (score 2):

Another option to run Sketchup without wine is setting up a Virtual Machine and installing Sketchup on it. Still you might (and probably will) need the registry change that cscarney proposed.

Answer (score 2):

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-google-sketchup-ubuntu1404/

this is detailed instructions for 2014 sketchup, also has detailed instructions resolving hangups and video problems.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

First install WINE with `sudo apt-get install wine`

Next, download the SketchUp installer from Google and save it to disk. Open a terminal and run `wine /path/to/installer.exe`  Finish the installer process.

Try running SketchUp (It's on the Applications menu under Wine/Applications).  If you get a "Couldn't Intitialize OpenGL" error, run `wine regedit.exe` and set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\SketchUp6\GLConfig\Display\HW_OK to 1.